# How to use array of regex pattern to check the url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have array of regex pattern, i want to check the url which matches the regex and use it.
please let me know the best way to do it.

The code i have written is something like this.

```
var a = ['^\/(.*)\/product_(.*)','(.*)cat_(.*)'];
var result = a.exec("/Duracell-Coppertop-Alkaline-AA-24-Pack/product_385346");
```

Expected:

when i use a.exec it should parse the url "/Duracell-Coppertop-Alkaline-AA-24-Pack/product_385346"

and give results.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your regex array:

```
var a = [/^\/(.*)\/product_(.*)/, /(.*)cat_(.*)/];
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var result = a[i].exec("/Duracell-Coppertop-Alkaline-AA-24-Pack/product_385346");
  results.push(result);
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: You can't `exec` strings, and you might want to mention you'll be overwriting `result` each iteration.

Comment: @Cerbrus I do not exec strings. In `a` array there are regex elements.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the regexes like this:

```
var a = ['^\/(.*)\/product_(.*)','(.*)cat_(.*)'];
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    result.push(RegExp(a[i]).exec("/Duracell-Coppertop-Alkaline-AA-24-Pack/product_385346"));
}
```

All matches are then stored in `result`.

`result[0]` is a array with matches from the regex in `a` at index `0`, `result[1]` --> `a[1]`, etc. If there are no results from the regex, `result[x]` will be `null`.

Instead of pushing the regex result to a array, you could also work on the result directly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var currentResult = RegExp(a[i]).exec("/Duracell-Coppertop-Alkaline-AA-24-Pack/product_385346");
    // Do stuff with currentResult here.
}
```